# Compare 2 java objects with 1000 properties in fastest way

Tags: java, reflection

I have 2 objects of the **same** class with **1000** properties.

They both have **similar** values in the properties.

What is the **fastest** way to find the **properties** which have different values apart from the **compareTo()** method in which they are checked for the properties one by one.

Comment: Its a general question. I am trying to explore the scenario where such use case is given and you have to find the difference. Currently I am aware of compareTo() method which does that but that would be a little tedious since it compares field by field..

Comment: `compareTo` is slower than `equals`, but you need to compare them one by one.

Comment: It's O(n), no matter what you do.  1,000 properties?  Abominable.  Have you thought about a refactoring for that beast?

Comment: Are there big similarities between object. I.e. if we have two instances, which percent of these 1000 fields will usually be equal?

Comment: What exactly are "1000 properties"?